# Schedule Mail batch by Rails in Cloud Foundry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud-foundry

I want to send email batch at specific time like CRON.

I think whenever gem (https://github.com/javan/whenever) is not to fit in Cloud Foundry Environment. Because Cloud Foundry can't use crontab.

Please inform me what options are available to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a node.js app [here](https://github.com/18F/cg-cron) that you could use to schedule a specific rake task.

I haven't worked with cloudfare so I'm not sure if it'll serve your needs, but you can also try some of the batch job processing tools rails has available: [Delayed job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) and [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq). Those store data for recurring jobs either on your database (DJ) or in a separate redis database (Sidekiq) and both need keeping extra processes up and running, so review them deeply and the changes you'd need for your deployment process before using each one. There's also resque, and [here's a tutorial to use it with rails for scheduling tasks](https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/scheduling-tasks-on-cloud-foundry).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions here, but the short answer is that whatever you end up doing needs to implement its own scheduler.  This is because there is no cron service available to your application when it runs on CF.  This means there is nothing to trigger or schedule your actions.  Any project or solution that depends on cron will not work when deploying to CF.  Any project that implements it's own scheduler should work fine.

Some specific things I've seen people do successfully:

- Use a web service that sends HTTP requests to your app on predefined intervals.  The requests trigger your action.  It's the services responsibility to let you define when to trigger and to send the HTTP requests.  I'm intentionally avoiding mentioning any specific services, but you can find them by searching for "cron http service" or something like that.
- Importing a library that has cron like functionality.  I'm not familiar with Ruby, so I don't know the landscape there.  @mlabarca has mentioned a couple that you might try out.  Again, look to see that they implement the scheduling functionality and do *not* depend on cron.  I'm more familiar with Java where you have Quartz and Spring, which has some scheduling functionality too.
- Implement a "clock" process or scheduler.  This would generally be a second app that you deploy on CF.  It would be lightweight and probably not have a web interface.  It could be as simple as do something, sleep, loop for ever repeating those two steps.  It really depends on your needs.  You could even get fancy and implement something like the first option above where you're sending some sort of request to your other apps to trigger the actual events.

There are probably other solutions as well, those are just some examples to get you started.

Probably also worth mentioning that the [Cloud Controller v3 API will have first class features to run tasks](http://v3-apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/version/3.1.0/index.html#tasks).  In this case, the "task" is some job that runs in a finite amount of time and exits (like a batch job).  This is opposed to the standard "app" that when run on CF should continue executing forever (i.e. if it exits, it's cause of a crash).  That said, I do not believe it will include a scheduler so you'd still need something to trigger the task.